# how to send request to specific client from socket.io server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm, socket.io

I'm saving the users data in an array see the below code
**server code**

```
socket.on('add user', function(data) {
   if (users.indexOf(data.id) == -1) {
    users.push({
            id: socket.id,
            userId: data.id,
            firstName: data.firstName,
            lastName: data.lastName
        });     
    }

    len = users.length;
    len--;
    io.emit('user join', users, users[len].userId, users[len].id);
});
```

I'm sending request from front end to a user for that first i'm checking whether user in online or not for sending request to specific user. If user there I'm assigning user socket.id to userId variable based on that I'm sending data see the below code
**server code**

```
socket.on('addNewFriend', function(userId) {
    console.log(userId);
    for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){
        if(users[i].userId==userId){
            var socketid=users[i].id;
            console.log(socketid);
    io.to(socketid).emit('addFriend',"hai");

        }
    }


});
```

Comment: How did you get on with the below, Bharath? While it is not mandatory to accept or vote on answers, it is nice to do so, as it is our way of encouraging helpful people to keep assisting people. Did you successfully complete this task?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping just the socket Id, keep the socket connection itself as well.

```
users.push({
    id: socket.id,
    socket: socket
    userId: data.id,
    firstName: data.firstName,
    lastName: data.lastName
});
```

It would be easier, if you use a map, instead of an array to save users,

```
users[socket.id] = {
    socket: socket
    userId: data.id,
    firstName: data.firstName,
    lastName: data.lastName
}
```

Then when you want to send a message, use the socket connection,

```
users[socketId].socket.emit(/*args*/)
```

If you save sockets in an array instead, you will need to filter the user object manually and then do the same.

**Edit**: So the full code for the listener is as below,

```
socket.on('addNewFriend', function(userId) {
    for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){
        if(users[i].userId == userId){
            var socketId = users[i].id;
            console.log(socketId);
            users[socketId].socket.emit('addFriend', "hai");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @BharathReddy What do u mean by 'how to do in front end '

Comment: socket.on('addNewFriend', function(userId) {
  for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){
   if(users[i].userId==userId){
    var socketid=users[i].id;
   users[socketid].emit('addFriend',"hai");
   }
  }
  });

Comment: In above code  I'm sending my Friend Id from front end based on that i'm checking  the id and doing that .But As Your perception how to compare  with my friend id ?

Comment: @Bharath I didn't write the complete code(expecting you would understand the concept). The last line should be executed only once you have got hold of the socketId. Let me edit the answer.